# Kafka transactionLog fails with NotEnoughReplicasException, despite correct config

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm having issues with reads from Kafka failing in our single-node dev environments

We are running a single-node kafka instance, and single-node Zookeeper -- as this is a dev env, we don't really care about replication.

We're using Kafka as an event store for Akka persistence.  When we attempt to read messages (even from an empty topic) we're getting `NotEnoughReplicasException` raised:

```
[2018-05-03 16:57:00,880] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=0] Error processing append operation on partition __transaction_state-7 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotEnoughReplicasException: Number of insync replicas for partition __transaction_state-7 is [1], below required minimum [2]
[2018-05-03 16:57:00,889] INFO [Transaction State Manager 0]: TransactionalId akka-journal-message-AkkaJavaSpring-4 append transaction log for TxnTransitMetadata(producerId=6000, producerEpoch=0, txnTimeoutMs=60000, txnState=Empty, topicPartitions=Set(), txnStartTimestamp=-1, txnLastUpdateTimestamp=1525366620855) transition failed due to COORDINATOR_NOT_AVAILABLE, resetting pending state from Some(Empty), aborting state transition and returning COORDINATOR_NOT_AVAILABLE in the callback (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionStateManager)
```

I have configured the following settings:

```
"min.insync.replicas": 1
"offsets.topic.replication.factor": 1
"transaction.state.log.replication.factor": 1
"transaction.state.log.min.isr" : 1
```

which is confirmed in the output of the config logged on startup:

```
[2018-05-03 16:33:34,381] INFO KafkaConfig values: 
    ...snip...
    min.insync.replicas = 1
    num.io.threads = 8
    num.network.threads = 3
    num.partitions = 1
    ...snip...
    transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
    transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
    transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
```

However, querying the `__transactionLog` topic seems to report it's `min.insync.replicas` set to 2:

```
/usr/bin/kafka-topics --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --describe

Topic:__transaction_state       PartitionCount:50       ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,unclean.leader.election.enable=false,compression.type=uncompressed,cleanup.policy=compact,min.insync.replicas=2
        Topic: __transaction_state      Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __transaction_state      Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __transaction_state      Partition: 2    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __transaction_state      Partition: 3    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

I'm using Kafka 1.0.0, as shown in the logs:

```
 INFO Kafka version : 1.0.0-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
```

What is causing this, and what is the correct config to prevent these exceptions from occuring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config posted above turned out to be correct.

However, the Zookeeper instance had been incorrectly configured when the topic was **initially** created, and replaying messages from the log seemed to throw the error.

Deleting the Zookeeper instance and starting again from fresh resolved the error

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting the zookeeper instance and starting again, I would suggest to decrease the `min.insync.replicas` for topics `__transaction_state`, `__transactionLog` (or if there are others) to 1. This can be fairly achieved by using the `kafka-configs.sh`  utility.

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server [host]:[port] --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name __transaction_state --add-config min.insync.replicas=1
```

Perform this operation on topics with `min.insync.replicas` = 2. As the value of insync replicas for topics fall to 1, Kafka will again check the criteria that min insync replicas for a topic should be equal to the value set in the config and this time the producer will be able to write to the topic without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the replication factor to 2,This could be because in sync replicas for the topic partition has fallen below min.insync.replicas

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/cluster/Partition.scala#L569-L572

```
if (inSyncSize < minIsr && requiredAcks == -1) {
    throw new NotEnoughReplicasException("Number of insync replicas for partition %s is [%d], below required minimum [%d]"
      .format(topicPartition, inSyncSize, minIsr))
}
```

This is where the exception occurs. you set  min.insync.replicas = 2 but  isr size is 1 (ISR: 0)

you prepare two or more brokers and
create topic with option --replication-factor 2

Comment: I set `min.insync.replicas = 1`, as shown in the output of the config in my question.  (similarly with `transaction.state.log.replication.factor` and `transaction.state.log.min.isr`)

Answer (score 0):

set insync and default replication to same value 
min.insync.replicas=1
default.replication.factor=1

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know that from version (2.3.0) to version (2.7.0) I have found that this line "offsets.topic.replication.factor=1" has changed which causes the dreaded error (sometimes this line is present and hardcoded to 1).

> "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotEnoughReplicasException: The size
> of the current ISR Set(0) is insufficient to satisfy the min.isr
> requirement of 2 for partition"

Of course, this collides with "min.insync.replicas" you set. Since I run a shell script before starting Kafka I just look for that line and comment it out and that makes the "__consumer_offsets" topic go to the default "default.replication.factor" you set.